# Expectation related to sparse Gaussian random vectors

Tags: probability

Let $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I_n)$ be $n$ dimensional Gaussian random vector and $Y=(Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_n)\in\{0,1\}^n$ be a random vector which is independent of $X$ such that for all $\xi\in\{0,1\}^n$ with $\sum_{i}^{n}\xi_i=s$
$$
\mathrm{P}(Y=\xi)=\frac{1}{{n\choose s}}.
$$
Define $Z=(X_1Y_1,\ldots,X_nY_n)$. So random vector $Z$ is a sparse Gaussian random vector by uniformly selecting $s$ components of $X$. My question is what is the value of $\mathrm{E}(|\langle Z,x\rangle|)$ for a fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

I think the difficulty comes from the absolute value sign and I can compute $\mathrm{E}(|\langle Z,x\rangle|^2)$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{E}(|\langle Z,x\rangle|^2) &= \mathrm{E}(|(X\odot Y)^\top x|^2)\\
 &=\sum_j \mathrm{E}(|(X\odot \xi_j)^\top x|^2 \,| \, Y=\xi_j)\mathrm{P}(Y=\xi_j)\\
 &=\frac{{n-1 \choose s-1}}{{n\choose s}}\|x\|_2^2\\
 &= \frac{s}{n}\|x\|_2^2.
\end{align*}
But how do we compute $\mathrm{E}(|\langle Z,x\rangle|)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed $v$ the random variable $T=\langle X,v\rangle$ is distributed as $N(0,\|v\|^2)$. (It is gaussian, because it is a linear combination of independent gaussians; its variance is the sum of the squares of the coefficients.) By elementary calculus (or by the method of believing the [internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments)) we know $E|T|=\|v\|\sqrt{\frac 2\pi}$.  The calculus:  assuming $T\sim N(0,1)$, we have (where $\phi$ is the standard normal density) $$E|T|=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |t|\phi(t)\,dt=2\int_0^\infty t\phi(t)\,dt=\frac 2{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty t e^{-t^2/2} \,dt=\sqrt{\frac 2 \pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2/2}d(t^2/2)=\sqrt{\frac 2 \pi}
$$
and so on.

This is for fixed $v$.  Your $\langle Z,x\rangle=\langle X,V\rangle$ where $V=(Y_1x_1,Y_2x_2,\ldots,Y_nx_n)$, and your desired $E|\langle Z,x\rangle|=E ( E[|\langle X,V\rangle|\mid V])=\sqrt{2/\pi}E\| V\|$.
This last expectation is hard to compute:
$$E\|V\| = \frac{\sum_S \sqrt{\sum_{i\in S} x_i^2}}{\binom n s}$$
where $S$ ranges over all size-$s$ subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: How do you get $\langle Z,x\rangle$ is distributed as $N(0,\|x\|^2)$?

Comment: My computation shows that the second moment of $\langle Z, x\rangle$ is $\frac{s}{n}\|x\|_2^2$ instead of $\|x\|_2^2$.

Comment: Sorry: I misread the question, and got mixed up with variable names, etc.  I have rewritten my answer, which I hope makes more sense.